# Context.Request.Path not using app name on local IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Only when running on my local computer, on IIS, I'm facing this issue.
Using this code:

```
<form id="lang" ... asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" method="post">
```

the value of `Context.Request.Path`
will be **empty** when the browser url is

```
http://localhost/myapp
```

and  it will be `act1`
when the browser url is

```
http://localhost/myapp/act1
```

I need the to get the url with the app name as well (`myapp`).

Comment: What are you expecting in `asp-route-returnUrl` and additionally, could you please share how you hosted your application as well as how you are submitted request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only when running on my local computer, on IIS, I'm facing this issue.
> Using this code.

Generally, [@Context.Request.Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.path?view=aspnetcore-7.0) returns the virtual path of current request that mean your applciation controller and action name without your application [base path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.pathbase?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [query string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.querystring?view=aspnetcore-7.0) passed from request url. Thus, you are getting exactly the same.

> The value of Context.Request.Path will be empty when the browser url
> is

Based on your scenario and context you could either use [Uri Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-7.0) or you can combine both Request.Path and Request.QueryString together and finally pass to [asp-route-returnUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-7.0#asp-route) to get both controller and querystring.

Let's have a look in action..

**Using URI Class:**

[image]

If you look at URI class which has absolute path, absoluteUri and local path property what exact you need.

```cs
 var getFullPath = new Uri($"{Context.Request.Scheme}://{Context.Request.Host}{Context.Request.Path}{Context.Request.QueryString}");
```

**Combining Request Path and QueryString:**

You even can pass combination of Request Path and QueryString together as following:

```cs
var getCombinePath = $"{Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
```

[image]

**Complete Implementation:**

```cs
@{
    var getCombinePath = $"{Context.Request.Path.Value}{Context.Request.QueryString}";
    var getFullPath = new Uri($"{Context.Request.Scheme}://{Context.Request.Host}{Context.Request.Path}{Context.Request.QueryString}");
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form id="lang" ... asp-route-returnurl="@getCombinePath" method="post" role="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class=" col-1 my-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: `getFullPath` in my case would output `http://localhost`, what works now is
`var getFullPath = Context.Request.PathBase + Context.Request.Path;`
`PathBase` being equal to `/myapp`

Comment: Then try another way either should work as expected. In addition, how do you hosted your app and where?

Comment: I'm hosting it in shared asp.net hosting, I only have this problem locally.

Comment: Thanks for the information, It will help to get expected result.